# Log File isn't produced when bat file is run as administrator

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I am having problem on generating a log file (Export_Files_Logs.log) when I run the bat file as administrator. But when I just double click the bat file. The log file is produced. Any idea why is this happening?

```
FOR %%f IN (D:\batch\outbound\Delta_Sync\Data\Log\*.log) DO type %%f >> Export_Files_Logs.log & echo. >> Export_Files_Logs.log
pause
```

Comment: What is the difference in your procedure?  What do you mean by saying you run it as administrator?

Comment: @SDsolar. I just right click the bat file and run it as administrator.

Comment: @MarkJimA.Mercado Check and see whether your log file is being saved in C:\Windows\System32.  If so, you should probably insert a `cd /d "%~dp0"` or `pushd "%~dp0"` into the top of your script.  The current working directory might not be the location of the batch script when you right-click and run as admin.

Comment: Yet you can't tell what directory it is using to start it.  Default is C:/Windows/system32.  I'll bet you find them there.  See my answer for three ways to ensure you have full control.  The first one is a kludge but works.  The others are the "Windows Way"

Comment: @SDsolar. Thank you very much. :) I am now able to produce the log file by adding the cd /d "%~dp0" on top of my script. But since you've mentioned that it was a kludge I'll indicate the exact path instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your log file will be in:

`C:\Windows\System32`

instead do this:

```
@echo off
FOR %%f IN (D:\batch\outbound\Delta_Sync\Data\Log\*.log) 
DO type %%f >> D:\batch\Export_Logs\Export_Files_Logs.log & echo. >> D:\batch\Export_Logs\Export_Files_Logs.log\Export_Files_Logs.log
pause
```

Add the paths you require, not mine :)

Answer (score 0):

The log file is probable created, but it's not saved were you think it should be.
Search for the "Export_Files_Logs.log" file using windows explorer to find were it was actually saved.
You can solve the issue by writing the full path before the file name.

Comment: You are right, and I would upvote you if you had specified where they did end up..  It is very predictable.  Just type cmd into the start menu and see where it starts you.